# Hibernate5: how to get Root<Long> for a record-count query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have this code

```
final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
final CriteriaBuilder builder = sessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<ListingDetailBaseDto> criteria = builder.createQuery(ListingDetailBaseDto.class);
final Root<ListingDetailBaseDto> root = criteria.from(ListingDetailBaseDto.class);
```

`...`

```
public int countRecords() {
    final CriteriaQuery<Long> countingQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
    countingQuery.select(countingQuery.from(Long.class));
    countingQuery.select(builder.count(root));
    final Query<Long> query = session.createQuery(countingQuery);
    return query.getSingleResult().intValue();
}
```

It says Long is not a valid entity. So I remove line 3,

```
public int countRecords() {
    final CriteriaQuery<Long> countingQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
    countingQuery.select(builder.count(root));
    final Query<Long> query = session.createQuery(countingQuery);
    return query.getSingleResult().intValue();
}
```

And then the error becomes: `No criteria query roots were specified`

How can I get this simple record count???

Comment: How do you define `root`?

Comment: Added to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @O.Badr for asking about `root`, that got me looking a little more closely at that part of the code.

The problem was caused by using `root` from a different `CriteriaQuery` object.

Fixed code:

```
public int countRecords() {
    final CriteriaQuery<Long> countingQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
    countingQuery.select(builder.count(countingQuery.from(ListingDetailBaseDto.class)));
    final Query<Long> query = session.createQuery(countingQuery);
    return query.getSingleResult().intValue();
}
```

Comment: Great that you've found it, so now you can accept your answer!

Answer (score -1):

Slightly off topic, but we ditched hibernate, so much nicer imo.

```
class ListingDetailsDao extends JdbcDaoSupport {

    public ListingDetailsDao (@Autowired @Qualifier("myDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    public int count() {

        final String sql = "select count (*) from listing_details";
        return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
    }
```